# How to run nosy (IEEE 1394 packet sniffer)

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, firewire

As far as I understand, [nosy](https://lwn.net/Articles/397005/) is an IEEE1394 FireWire packet sniffer for linux. I'm unsure as how to run it. It can be found in the [linux repo](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/firewire).

When I `cd` to `/lib/modules/4.15.0-55-generic/kernel/drivers/firewire`, there's a file called `nosy.ko`, which is a linux kernel module. I tried `sudo insmod nosy.ko` and loaded the module (can see it in the output of `lsmod`) but nothing happened.

Kernel: 4.15.0-55-generic

Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (bionic)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @user535733 changed the title. It's included with ubuntu, but how do I run / make use of it, so I can sniff FireWire packets?

Comment: It is unclear why you think nosy.ko is a packet sniffer. You might as well say it's a bread slicer or a coffee maker, which makes no sense either way.

Comment: @mikewhatever That's what its developers call it. See [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/397005/). The term is also used by wikipedia when defining a [packet analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer). Can you please help me with my problem?

Comment: Apparently, there is a "userspace frontend, called nosy-dump", so that's what you "run". You are welcome to read the article: https://lwn.net/Articles/397005/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on @mikewhatever's comment, and [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/ffado/mailman/message/30412944/) thread, I ran `make` in the `tools/firewire` subdirectory of the kernel source tree. If there are no errors (see below) that will result in a nosy-dump executable that you can run. Your nosy device might not be `/dev/nosy` as written in the code so you can change that before compiling or use the `-d` flag. In my case the devices are `fw0` and `fw1`, since I'm using a laptop PCI card with 2 FW interfaces. Check out the code for the rest of the flags. I don't get any output upon running `nosy-dump`, but that's another problem.

If you could compile then don't read any further.

I got an error saying that `uapi/linux/types.h` could not be found. I had to add an extra include path in the `MakeFile`, on line 9, so that it looks like `nosy-dump : CFLAGS = -Wall -O2 -g -I /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-55-generic/include/uapi`. Of course, this path depends on the kernel and distro.